# File local variable setting for custom folding per file type

Tags: scope, vim

I have the following variable in vimrc that customizes the fold heading text:

```
let &foldtext = "EightHeaderFolds( '\\=s:fullwidth-3', 'left', [ repeat( '   ', v:foldlevel - 1 ), '.', '' ], '\\= s:foldlines . \" lines\"', '' )"
```

I would like to change this variable for a specific file type such as .otl. I want it to become as the following for .otl files:

```
let &foldtext = "EightHeaderFolds( '\\=s:fullwidth-3', 'left', [ repeat( '  ', v:foldlevel - 1 ), '.', '' ], '\\= s:foldlines . \" lines\"', '' )"
```

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From [Vim FAQ 26.1](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/vim_faq.txt.html#faq-26.1):

```
26.1. How do I set different options for different types of files?

You can create filetype plugins to set different options for different
types of files. You should first enable filetype plugins using the command: 

    :filetype plugin on

A filetype plugin is a vim script that is loaded whenever Vim opens or
creates a file of that type.  For example, to ensure that the 'textwidth'
option is set to 80 when editing a C program (filetype 'c'), create one of
the following files: 

        ~/.vim/ftplugin/c.vim (Unix)
        %HOME%\vimfiles\ftplugin\c.vim (Windows)

with the following text in it: 

        setlocal textwidth=80

You can also use autocommands to set specific options when editing specific
type of files. For example, to set the 'textwidth' option to 75 for only
*.txt files, you can use the following autocmd: 

    autocmd BufRead *.txt setlocal textwidth=80
```

I'd favor the ftplugin approach, in order to make it easier to find and avoid cluttering the .vimrc with autocmds and functions that are specific to some filetypes. Check `:help filetype-plugin` for more details on how to create it.